# Qt Installer Framework to distribute closed source project

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, license-recommendation, license-notice, license

I work for a company where I'm developing an application based on a number of Qt components. We want o keep application source code closed and use Qt for free, I understand that means use Qt under LGPL.

So now is time to distribute our application (to other legal entities). Can I pack it with Qt Installer framework?